# How to change TextBox Font Color if the value is "Out of Scope."

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, textbox

The Font Colour in textbox (PIC_Name_Box_CO) won't change into somewhat i designed. Kindly need your help.

I already did some condition at the textbox (PIC_Name_Box_CO). But it wont't change its colour.. i also tried to remove the "Locked" condition. Please help.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()     
 PIC_Name_Box_CO.Locked = True
End Sub

Private Sub Purchasing_Group_List_CO_Change()

     Dim a, b

    a = Purchasing_Group_List_CO.value
    b = Application.VLookup(a, _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("A195:B230"), 2, False)

    PIC_Name_Box_CO.value = IIf(IsError(b), "Out of Scope.", b)

    PIC_Name_Box_CO.BackColor = &HC0FFFF
    PIC_Name_Box_CO.Locked = True

End Sub

Private Sub PIC_Name_Box_CO_Change()

    If PIC_Name_Box_CO.value = "Out of scope" Then
    PIC_Name_Box_CO.ForeColor = &HFF&
    Else: PIC_Name_Box_CO.ForeColor = &H0&
    End If

End Sub
```

I want to change the TextBox's Value into Red (&H000000FF&) if the value is an error result "Out of Scope."

Comment: I have not worked much on forms but the syntax for font color change is something like `Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = vbBlack`

Comment: The code in the PIC_Name_Box_CO_Change event works for me, but please note the comparison is *case-sensitive*.

Comment: Yes indeed it works, my apologies forgot about those little details. Thanks for the reply. @CindyMeister